# How to run Elite Dangerous on MacBook Air M1

Tags: windows-10, macos, mac, macbook, arm

**My problem:**
My high school requires me to have an apple computer, so my parents are going to get me a MacBook Air M1 and I was wondering if and how I can play [Elite Dangerous](https://store.steampowered.com/app/359320/Elite_Dangerous/) on that computer.

I know there is no mac version for Elite Dangerous so I will need to install Windows 10 (does anyone know how to do that? I heard something about Bootcamp) and I believe the M1 is an ARM processor so I wonder if Elite Dangerous and Windows 10 can run on ARM.

**NOTE:** I DO NOT want a Windows emulator I also want to use other windows features like coding C++, C# and not just run Elite Dangerous.
Other note, i'm a kid, so please make it easy to understand and follow through

**My goal of this post:** To run Elite Dangerous on Windows 10 on a MacBook Air M1

Comment: Because of the transition issues Ramhound points out below, it might be wiser to ask for an Intel Mac for the next couple of years, until the M1/ARM processors are further supported. Then you could run Boot Camp or a VM with Windows. There's a rumour Apple will be announcing new products in a couple of weeks. If that's more M1 Macs, the price of the last of the Intels will drop again.

Comment: Another point - if you decide to run Windows in a VM on an Intel Mac, you'd be better off with a Macbook Pro than an Air. The airs are a bit lightweight for serious processing.

Comment: Didn’t Apple announced they have discontinued the MacBook Pro?

Comment: @Ramhound - They currently sell MacBook Air as M1 only, but the MacBook Pro as M1 or Intel. It's the iMac Pro [currently Intel only] that is rumoured to be being discontinued, however is still available for purchase from the Apple Store.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I knew something was being discontinued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there is no mac version for Elite Dangerous so I will need to install Windows 10 (does anyone know how to do that?

It’s **impossible** to run Windows 10 on an Apple device with a M1 Apple ARM processor.

> I heard something about Bootcamp) and I believe the M1 is an ARM processor so I wonder if Elite Dangerous and Windows 10 can run on ARM.

BootCamp would only be appropriate to run Elite Dangerous if you going to purchase an Apple device with an x86 Intel processor.

> I DO NOT want a Windows emulator I also want to use other windows features like coding C++, C# and not just run Elite Dangerous. Other note, i'm a kid, so please make it easy to understand and follow through

Even if you want to use an emulator, the software you want to run, is incompatible with an ARM processor.

> My goal of this post: To run Elite Dangerous on Windows 10 on a MacBook Air M1

Your goal cannot be achieved.  Windows 10 cannot run on the device, which means you cannot run a Windows 10 VM on the device, which means you cannot run Elite Dangerous on the device.

Elite Dangerous doesn’t run on Windows 10 on ARM. It would not matter if it did, gaming within a VM isn’t easy, and Elite Dangerous would run absolutely horribly on an Apple device with an M1 processor since it doesn’t have an adequate GPU.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. You can install Parallels Preview, then install Windows on Arm Technical Preview, which can install Elite Dangerous with Steam. It runs better than in most Windows laptops, check it https://youtu.be/edHU5r98zrQ

Comment: Good find. Thought it would be an outright no.